# Teen novel about a biological attack, a quarantined area and two siblings

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in the 1990s, it was definitely oriented toward the teen reader, and the book was in English.

The gist of the book was that there had been a biological attack against the country (which I think may have been England), but there was some lead up to this which allowed for an orderly evacuation to happen.

Unfortunately, the main character (I'm thinking a teen boy) and their sibling (I'm thinking a younger boy) missed the evacuation because they were asleep in their house at the time, and the older sibling ignored the knocking on the door.

The main story line is that the country is now split into two, with a large wall or fence blocking one area, the quarantined area, from the rest of the country. Most people died in the quarantined area due to the biological attack, but some survived as immunes to form gangs.  I'm pretty sure the younger sibling died during involvements with these gangs.

The main memory of this book is that the non-quarantined area air-dropped a communications cabin into the quarantined area, and the main character used to talk to the outside world using it - during one of these scenes, he sees an animal (dog, wolf or something that size) and wonders how it got through the fence, as it could only have come from the outside world.

The main character was also in conflict with another immune, possibly over the communications cabin.

I'm pretty sure the story was told in a roundabout way, with the opening and closing scenes being of the main character in the cabin and most of the rest of the story being told as flash backs or storyline jumps to previous points in time.